# Modifying textbox to have some text that disappears upon clicking using the placeholder attribute

Tags: php, javascript, html, placeholder

I am trying to modify a textbox on my webpage so that it has some text written in it that disapears once the user clicks on the textbox to enter the information. I have tried using the placeholder attribute, with no luck. I then tried adding this: (https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) to make placeholder work, again it did not work (textbox remains blank).

I am a beginner at programming, using Internet Explorer 8.

Here is the code:

```
<td colspan="3">    

    <textarea style="background: #F6E3CE; overflow:auto;" rows="3" cols="70" name="" id="" placeholder="Please enter your name here" onchange="commentsChanged(this,<?php echo $variable;?>);"><?php echo str_replace('\r\n', "\n", rtrim($variable2[0][TitleTitle]));?></textarea>

</td>
```

Please let me know if any information is missing.

Thank you!

Comment: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text/comment-page-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can do this: (I not test, but this is not far)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input#text").focus(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == "default message" )
        {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == "" )
        {
            $(this).val("default message");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I really want to use your solution because I know how good jQuery is, but I haven't worked with it before... Do I insert this code into my <textarea> code or is it referenced out of a seperate file?

Comment: You can add an external file or do in the same file that the textarea. Remember that the code is needed in the file that is the textarea. Maybe you need to put this code in a window load event "$(window).load(function(){... THE CODE HERE WITHOUT <script> TAG ...});"

Answer (score 0):

Or without jQuery:

HTML code

```
<textarea onFocus="placeholder(this, ´focus´)" onBlur="placeholder(this, ´blur´)">Default value</textarea>
```

JavaScript code

```
<script>

function placeholder(el, w) {


    if (el.value == "Default value" && w == "focus") el.value = "";
    if (el.value == "" && w == "blur") el.value = "Default value";


}

</script>
```